# how to handle exception happened inside @SchedulerLock

Tags: spring-boot, exception, shedlock

We have Spring boot API which use  Quartz and shedlock for our batch. We have bellow exception when it try to put lock for batch job and the database connection is not abvailable. we are using annotation

```
@SchedulerLock(name = "AurCifBatchTask", lockAtLeastFor = "${quartz.cif.batch.lock-at-least}", lockAtMostFor = "${quartz.cif.batch.lock-at-most}")
```

Because this exception happened before our batch job get started so we can not catch it in our code.

So my question is: What we can do to catch this exception happened in `@SchedulerLock` annotation?

```
2023-07-11T12:54:30.026-04:00 ERROR 33453 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task

org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:309) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at net.javacrumbs.shedlock.provider.jdbctemplate.JdbcTemplateStorageAccessor.execute(JdbcTemplateStorageAccessor.java:119) ~[shedlock-provider-jdbc-template-5.3.0.jar:na]
    at net.javacrumbs.shedlock.provider.jdbctemplate.JdbcTemplateStorageAccessor.updateRecord(JdbcTemplateStorageAccessor.java:82) ~[shedlock-provider-jdbc-template-5.3.0.jar:na]
    at net.javacrumbs.shedlock.support.StorageBasedLockProvider.doLock(StorageBasedLockProvider.java:90) ~[shedlock-core-5.3.0.jar:na]
    at net.javacrumbs.shedlock.support.StorageBasedLockProvider.lock(StorageBasedLockProvider.java:62) ~[shedlock-core-5.3.0.jar:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:216) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy88.lock(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at net.javacrumbs.shedlock.core.DefaultLockingTaskExecutor.executeWithLock(DefaultLockingTaskExecutor.java:60) ~[shedlock-core-5.3.0.jar:na]
    at net.javacrumbs.shedlock.spring.aop.MethodProxyScheduledLockAdvisor$LockingInterceptor.invoke(MethodProxyScheduledLockAdvisor.java:83) ~[shedlock-spring-5.3.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:702) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at com.rbc.imw0.digital.aur.service.AurResourceService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.populateCIFInfo(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:96) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: aur-service - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30002ms.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:696) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:181) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:146) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:265) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the host YKE0-D16GP0108.devfg.rbc.com, named instance in08 failed. Error: "java.net.UnknownHostException: YKE0-D16GP0108.devfg.rbc.com". Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434.  For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:234) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getInstancePort(SQLServerConnection.java:5963) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.primaryPermissionCheck(SQLServerConnection.java:2383) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2126) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1993) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1164) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:760) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:733) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:712) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted

2023-07-11T12:56:30.010-04:00 ERROR 33453 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task

org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:309) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at net.javacrumbs.shedlock.provider.jdbctemplate.JdbcTemplateStorageAccessor.execute(JdbcTemplateStorageAccessor.java:119) ~[shedlock-provider-jdbc-template-5.3.0.jar:na]
    at net.javacrumbs.shedlock.provider.jdbctemplate.JdbcTemplateStorageAccessor.updateRecord(JdbcTemplateStorageAccessor.java:82) ~[shedlock-provider-jdbc-template-5.3.0.jar:na]
    at net.javacrumbs.shedlock.support.StorageBasedLockProvider.doLock(StorageBasedLockProvider.java:90) ~[shedlock-core-5.3.0.jar:na]
    at net.javacrumbs.shedlock.support.StorageBasedLockProvider.lock(StorageBasedLockProvider.java:62) ~[shedlock-core-5.3.0.jar:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:216) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy88.lock(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at net.javacrumbs.shedlock.core.DefaultLockingTaskExecutor.executeWithLock(DefaultLockingTaskExecutor.java:60) ~[shedlock-core-5.3.0.jar:na]
    at net.javacrumbs.shedlock.spring.aop.MethodProxyScheduledLockAdvisor$LockingInterceptor.invoke(MethodProxyScheduledLockAdvisor.java:83) ~[shedlock-spring-5.3.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:702) ~[spring-aop-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at com.rbc.imw0.digital.aur.service.AurResourceService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.populateCIFInfo(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:96) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: aur-service - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30004ms.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:696) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:181) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:146) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:265) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the host YKE0-D16GP0108.devfg.rbc.com, named instance in08 failed. Error: "java.net.UnknownHostException: YKE0-D16GP0108.devfg.rbc.com". Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434.  For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:234) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getInstancePort(SQLServerConnection.java:5963) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.primaryPermissionCheck(SQLServerConnection.java:2383) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2126) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1993) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1164) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:760) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:733) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:712) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
```

I tried different way, But could not catch this exception. I would like to catch it so when the batch job failed we can get noticed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I override StorageBasedLockProvider class and add some additional logic to handle the exception. It works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1. It's not clear why would you use ShedLock with Quartz, if you have Quartz, ShedLock should not be necessary.
2. What do you want to do when you catch the exception?
3. But if you really need to catch the exception, you can implement `LockProvider` interface, wrap the original one and implement the exception hacking there.

Comment: we want to catch the exception and log it use our own error code.

Comment: Thanks Lukas, we tried Quartz with MS SQL server, it could not setup the locker. I can see mutiple instances run the batch in the same time. So I have to use ShedLock.

Comment: @user:277042  could you please provide some details regarding 3. How to implement that?

Comment: @BruceXie https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock#customization